# RODBC : Single Backslash in server name

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I have the following issue : the SQL server I am trying to connect to using RODBC has a backslash in it.

Here is my code:

```
library(RODBC)
server <- "servername\REP"
database<- "databasename"
connectionString <- paste("Driver={SQL Server};server=",server,";database=",database,";trusted_connection=yes;")
channel <-  odbcDriverConnect(connection=connectionString)
```

Of course \R causes an issue and the channel cannot be opened. One solution would be to escape the backslash:

```
   server <- "servername\\REP"
```

But then the server name is not the right one anymore and the connection cannot be made.

Basically I am stuck needing
    server <- "servername\REP"
to work!

Surely someone has already encountered this issue...

Comment: `server <- "servername\\REP"` <-- this is the correct way to introduce a backslash into the string.  If this doesn't work, I think something else is wrong with your connection string.

Comment: All good, the error lied in using paste() instead of paste0()

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the solution here was using "paste0" to generate the connection string :

```
library(RODBC)
server <- "servername\REP"
database<- "databasename"
connectionString <- paste0("Driver={SQL Server};server=",server,";database=",database,";trusted_connection=yes;")
channel <-  odbcDriverConnect(connection=connectionString)
```

using "paste()" was adding pesky white spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Jogo!