# R - Backslash escaping issue

Tags: r

The overall problem that I am having is the same issue that comes up here:
[RODBC : Single Backslash in server name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48943629/rodbc-single-backslash-in-server-name)
but in this solution I am still having an issue:

when I use the following I get an error:

```
> server <- "test\server"
Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""test\s"
```

but trying to escape the backslash it doesn't change to just a single backslash and now the connection code cant find a server with two backslashes.

```
> server <- "test\\server"
> server
[1] "test\\server"
```

Comment: If your goal is to create a platform-independent file path, check out `file.path`

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(365)`